# how to use a bootstrap dropbox as a ui-router route selector

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a dropbox as a ui-router route selector nested in one of my pages for a col-xs. everything works fine except the label. I would like the default label on the Button to be 'Select'. And when I select a route from the list I would like that route to be displayed. And if possible I would like to use ng-class to highlight the button when any route is chosen. thanks

```
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%" id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     Select
    <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
  <ul style="width:100%" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
 <li><a ui-sref="tab1">Tab1</a></li>
 <li><a ui-sref="tab2">Tab2</a></li>
 <li><a ui-sref="tab3">Tab3</a></li>
 <li><a ui-sref="tab4">Tab4</a></li>
 <li><a ui-sref="tab5">Tab5</a></li>
 <li><a ui-sref="tab6">Tab6</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab1");
$stateProvider
    .state('tab1', {
        url: "/tab1",
        templateUrl: "views/services/tab1.html"
    })
    .state('tab2', {
        url: "/tab2",
        templateUrl: "views/services/tab2.html"
    })
 .state('tab3', {
     url: "/tab3",
     templateUrl: "views/services/tab3.html"
 })
    .state('tab4', {
        url: "/tab4",
        templateUrl: "views/services/tab4.html"
    })
.state('tab5', {
    url: "/tab5",
    templateUrl: "views/services/tab5.html"
})
    .state('tab6', {
        url: "/tab6",
        templateUrl: "views/services/tab6.html"
    })
```

}

Comment: read up on the various state change events and data associated. Then you can have a directive do your matching

Comment: Add $state to the scope of your template (or just put it on `$rootScope`), then you can use `{{ $state.current.name }}` in your templates.

Comment: @ChrisT  put in a answer so i can mark it as correct